# How to sort mongodb find results by the length of a string property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to sort my find results by the length of a particular string property. My schema has a sub property "comment" and I would like to sort by the length of the comment. 
I am running a find query something like this.

```
Model.find(query, callback)
.sort({ 'review.comment.length' : -1 })
```

Schema:

```
feedback = new Schema({
    review: {type: content}
})


content = new Schema({
   comment: {type: String},
   date: {type: Date}
})
```

This doesn't work though. Can someone help with the right query?

Comment: can you share your schema ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Added the relevant parts of schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)  framework and `$strLenCP` for this

Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate(
 [
  {
    {$match : {property : 'value'}} //This is your filter criteria
     $project: {

        length: { $strLenCP: "$review.comment" }
     }
  },
   {$sort:{length: -1}}
 ]
)
```

Comment: But I'm using find. How to accommodate aggregation framework here? Sorry, new to MongoDB world.

Comment: No need to accommodate. It's already there. Try this query on mongo shell first

Comment: let me know what comes out

Comment: I meant how can I use find and aggregate at the same time?

Comment: Oh. You can use`{$match : {property : "value'}}` pipeline to filter. This works just like filter in find

Comment: check updated code

Comment: Worked on my dev server. But I guess the production has an older version of mongodb where $strlenCP is invalid operator. Any ideas how I can make it work?